# How to access a locally-shared folder via UNC path when not connected to a network

Tags: windows-7, networking

As a developer, I have a program running called AppFabric.  AppFabric requires a UNC path to a shared folder to store its settings (for instance, `\\machine\share` pointing to **c:\folder_to_share**).  Now, sometimes I'm in a place where I can't connect to a network.  At those times, the UNC path `\\machine\share` doesn't appear to exist anymore.

So how would I access a UNC path pointing at a local share when I don't have a network connection?  This is in Windows 7.  Note that as soon as I connect to a network, the UNC path is usable again, and also note that this program will not allow drive letters but **requires** a UNC path (I know, boo!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the networking, or lack there of, is causing the issue you can always install the loopback adapter to force IP networking, even if its not there.

Comment: It was indeed the lack of network adapter.  Thanks for suggesting the Microsoft Loopback Adapter; a couple of minutes of googling and following directions, and I had it installed.  For others looking, here's the link I found and followed for Windows 7: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/259c7ef2-3770-4212-8fca-c58936979851/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a few other names to test are `\\localhost` and `\\ip.address.of.machine`.

If this doesn't work, I'm guessing that this is down to selecting `Public Network` as your zone/area in `Network and Sharing Centre` which disables File and Printer sharing.

With File and Printer sharing disabled, there is no way to emulate this (and I wouldn't recommend it for security reasons).

However, if you know what you are doing, you can either change the zone by clicking on it (1), or click on `Change Advanced Sharing Settings` (2) and manually enable it for your zone.

[image]

Comment: What if localhost works?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are not forming your UNC paths correctly (based on your post).  It should be `\\machine\share`.  You are missing a slash.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit! He was using double slash. If formatting gets messed up, try placing it in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, William, to clean up my formatting.  I had entered double-slash but didn't check close enough what the output was in the post.